# Don't you think that the tag "jesus" should be starting with a capital letter?

Tags: feature-request

I may be too picky here, but don't you think that the tag "jesus" should be starting with a capital letter?

Comment: I think it is best to think of tags as [case-insensitive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Case_sensitivity).

Comment: Not sure why you got downvoted, since it's a valid question, so I upvoted to right that wrong.

Comment: Especially since not everyone here is a programmer or a Christian.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

No not really a big deal in my opinion. Tags are traditionally always lower case, not just on this site but on a good many other sites as well. It would get very messy if they allowed upper case at all and doing it just for a couple proper names doesn't make much sense. I think it's better to just leave tags as all lower case.

On the other hand, in the titles and bodies of questions it should definitely be capitalized.

Answer (score -4):

Yes.

Would not hurt people to show a little respect

Answer (score -10):

It absolutely should be capitalized. Christians should not be the least bit afraid of standing out, much less in the case of having the only capitalized tag in all of SE. It is, after all, the name of Jesus. There is none other name under heaven, given among men, whereby we must be saved. To leave it lower case is to profane it to some extent.

Comment: I disagree strongly that leaving it lower case is "profaning" Jesus' name. Capitalization is an artifact of language (English in this case), proper nouns in English are capitalized, the word Jesus is treated the same way as say Visual Studio. In the language of SE tags, all words are equal in that they are all lower case. So in the example I just used Jesus should be lower cased, just like all other words in tags on SE. It isn't profanity or blasphemy, its using the language properly.

Comment: Just because it used to be ok doesn't mean it must be ok now. Most people looking at it who aren't regular SE users will find it a bit troubling. To profane means to take something holy and make it common. That absolutely fits this situation.

Comment: The power of Jesus' name is derived from the person of Christ, not the symbolic representation of his name. the letters j-e-s-u-s are not in any way holy, nor are they any holier when combined into a single word "jesus." Jesus is holy. Yes his name has power, but that power is not inherent to the symbolic representation of his name, and its not defamed by representing it in the way that is standard for SE site. The power of Jesus' name is there because it refers to Christ. Not capitalizing the name does not change the fact that it points to Christ.

Comment: @wax eagle - I am confused now. Why then Jesus said so many times "in My name" and, as far as I can remember, He never said "in My person"? At least the number of "in My name" or "for the sake of My name" outnumber all occurrences of "in My person" if any. Also, if we were talking about some character in the Bible whose name happened to be "Jesus", but who were not the Son of God, then the tag "jesus" would be just right for that, whereas the tag "Jesus" would still be appropriate only for the Son of God.

Comment: @brilliant - name there is actually referring to authority rather than the actual name. "In the Name of the King" means "By the Authority of the King." It has less to do with the words than the power they represent.

Comment: @wax eagle - You want to say that when Jesus said "Whosoever shall receive this child in my name receives Me" He was speaking merely about His authority? Or when He said "for many shall come in my name, saying, I am Christ" about false prophets, He meant to say that those false prophets would really come in His authority?

Comment: Just for clarity's sake, the practice of capitalizing Jesus' name, is not *just* out of following proper English grammar, since most Bibles also capitalize pronouns that are being used to refer to Him <- case in point. This is called "honorizing". We do the same with the word "God" when it refers to the god we believe in, and "god" when we are using the term generically, even though the word "God" isn't God's name (hence not a result of English grammar rules being applied).